# How To Save a Variable as a Data Frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I am new to R and programming in general and am trying to create a program that will collect and analyze data from twitter. The code I am using is below:

```
install.packages(c("devtools", "rjson", "bit64", "httr"))

library(devtools)

library(twitteR)

APIkey <- "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
APIsecret <- "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
accesstoken <- "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
accesstokensecret <- "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"

setup_twitter_oauth(APIkey,APIsecret,accesstoken,accesstokensecret)


Pat1$Patientsentiment <- tolower (Pat1$Patientcomment)

library(qdap)

Sent<-polarity(Pat1$Patientcomment, grouping.var = Pat1$Pat.NUMBER,

           positive.list = positive.words,

           negative.list = negative.words,

           negation.list = negation.words,

           amplification.list = increase.amplification.words,

           rm.incomplete = FALSE, digits = 3)

RPatient_Polarity <- data.frame(Sent$all)
```

I am trying to figure out how to save Pat1 as a data frame so that Pat1 is a data table from which you take Pat1$Patientcomment as variable.

When I run the program now, I get the following result:

```
> library(devtools)
> library(twitteR)
> APIkey <- "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
> APIsecret <- "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
> accesstoken <- "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
> accesstokensecret <- "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
> setup_twitter_oauth(APIkey,APIsecret,accesstoken,accesstokensecret)
[1] "Using direct authentication"
Error in check_twitter_oauth() : OAuth authentication error:
This most likely means that you have incorrectly called       
setup_twitter_oauth()'
> Pat1$Patientsentiment <- tolower (Pat1$Patientcomment)
> library(qdap)
> Sent<-polarity(Pat1$Patientcomment, grouping.var = Pat1$Pat.NUMBER,
+                
+                positive.list = positive.words,
+                
+                negative.list = negative.words,
+                
+                negation.list = negation.words,
+                
+                amplification.list = increase.amplification.words,
+                
+                rm.incomplete = FALSE, digits = 3)
Error in derive_pubkey(key) : 
  RAW() can only be applied to a 'raw', not a 'list'
> RPatient_Polarity <- data.frame(Sent$all)
Error in data.frame(Sent$all) : object 'Sent' not found
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `Sent[[all]]`. See if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I am working on a sentiment analysis. For polarities, I used the qdap package and having the same error for all reviews - for single sentences as well as for single words... 
why this happening?

```
library(qdap)    
polarity("I love to eat")
```

> Error in derive_pubkey(key) :
>   RAW() can only be applied to a
>   'raw', not a 'list'

I consulted [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22774913/estimating-document-polarity-using-rs-qdap-package-without-sentsplit).  Is there something I missed? `derive_pubkey(key)` - what does this mean?